# Encapsulation not initialized properly?

Tags: python, class, encapsulation

I was just playing around to know more about encapsulation and found out that we cannot print out values that has been encapsulated, we have to define a seperate method that prints the value out, but here in my code i tried to print out an attribute of my class and it worked, so is there a mistake in my encapsulation?

code :

```
class Time:
    timethytom = 'Best'

    def __init__(self, hours, minutes):
        self.__hours = hours
        self.__minutes = minutes

    def setTime(self,hour,minute):
        self.__hours = hour
        self.__minutes = minute

    def getTime(self):
        print(f'Time is {self.__hours}hr {self.__minutes}min')

    def addTime(self, hour1, hour2, minute1, minute2):
        print(f'{hour1+hour2} hours and {minute1+minute2} minutes')


time1 = Time(10, 20)

time1.setTime(20,5)
time1.hours = 55
time1.getTime()

print(time1.hours)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you are talking about `time1.hours = 55`, this is not the same as `self.__hours`. The latter is an encapsulated value and the first one is a public attribute that is created due to the assignment. Because it has been created, it can then be printed

Comment: so what should i do to make it private

Comment: You already did make it private. In Python, you simply cannot prevent people from adding attribute to existing instance like you did. Your encapsulation is already good. Small advice: prefer single leading underscore to double leading underscore unless you know exactly why you are doing it. It can lead to unforeseen problems and worse debugging experience

Comment: oh is there a diff b/w _ and __ ?

Comment: When you use single underscore, nothing happens and you can access the variable from outside the class (encapsulation) with the name as it is but if you use double underscore, then name mangling which appends the name of the class in front of the attribute (with a leading underscore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can create a public variables in the class from out of the class, something like this:

```
class xyz:
  pass

x = xyz()
x.y=10
print(x.y) #This will print 10
```

When you wrote this line `time1.hours = 55`, actually you have created a variable named `hours` in the object `time1` which is not the same as the variable `__hours` defined in the class.

Comment: You're welcome. I would recommend this page (https://dbader.org/blog/meaning-of-underscores-in-python) for you to read more about underscores in Python